# Laptop keeps generating heat after shutting down

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, battery, overheating

I have Ubuntu 16.10 installed on my Lenovo Thinkpad E460. Everything works just fine except that after I shut down the device it keeps generating heat (most likely at the graphics card) and drains energy. If I only suspend the device then no heat, no energy drain. This problem occured on Ubuntu 16.04 too.

Comment: You mean the  fan runs a few minutes after shutdown?  That's good behavior to keep from cooking the insides to let internal heat dissipate.

Comment: No, it keeps generating heat hours after shut down, the fan doesn't run that time.

Comment: Maybe the batteries are charged. But they should get ful after a reasonable time, and after that no heat should be generated. Otherwise something is wrong. Maybe the batteries are bad, or the some electronic component. What happens if you remove the batteries, and have the power plugged in? Will it still generate heat when turned off?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's very likely a hardware question and not an issue with Ubuntu.

Comment: Not sure about that because this machine was working just fine on other operating systems or distros.

Comment: Do you have anything on the USB port which is powered when shutdown?  Does the problem persist when that power-USB-when-off option is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues with a Lenovo X1 Yoga. It worked with 16.10 for a couple of months but stopped doing a complete shutdown about 2 or 3 months ago. About the same time it stopped suspending/resuming.

Note: I would Comment but the stupid kharma rules prevent me from using Comment right now.